# where to ask about website CMS, like wordpress SU or SO?

Tags: discussion, support, off-topic

Wordpress is technically computer software, but it is also programming and development. So where should I ask a question about a WP plugin on SO or SU?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions on what WP plugin to use, how to install the plugin would go to [ProWebmasters StackExchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Questions on how to program or debug a plugin would goto [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Question doesn't fit on SU as the SU FAQ clearly mentions:

> it is not about …
>
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and **WordPress**

Comment: thanks, I just wish SE would combine some of the littler sites so that more people see them, really it would be great to have notsuperuser.com or notstackoverflow.com, where you can ask computer related questions that don't fit exactly into SO or SU.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new SE site [dedicated to WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), currently in public beta. I think that, generally speaking, if your question involves WP, that site is the place to go.